# What is an example of a plant species that is a halophyte with seeds that germinate quickly?

Tags: botany, species-identification, seeds, germination

I’m doing an experiment on the effect of salt concentration on the germination of seeds from halophyte plants. What would be an example of a species that is suitable for such an experiment? I would prefer a species the seeds of which germinate relatively quickly under not very difficult conditions.

Comment: where have you tried looking for the answer to this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that your research question about halophytes has been asked many times before. You should learn from your predecessors...

Seed germination in halophytes displays a high degree of inter- and intra-specific variability. However, [Khan & Gul (2006)](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/226365945_Halophyte_Seed_Germination) report that germination patterns respond to a number of environmental factors (including temperature, NaCl concentration, and presence of different regulating chemicals).

- Their paper has over 100 citations, many of which cite germination studies of numerous halophyte species. I'd recommend you start your search there.

You'd also probably benefit by perusing the sources in [Ungar (1978)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/4353933?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) and [Panuccio et al. (2014)](https://academic.oup.com/aobpla/article/doi/10.1093/aobpla/plu047/2842731/Effect-of-saline-water-on-seed-germination-and).

[image]

**Citations**

- Khan, M.A. & B. Gul. 2006. Halophyte Seed Germination. In Halophyte Utilization and Regional Sustainable Development of Agriculture. pp.11-30
- Panuccio, M.R., S.E. Jacobsen, S.S. Akhtar and  A. Muscolo. 2014. Effect of saline water on seed germination and early seedling growth of the halophyte quinoa. AoB PLANTS 6: plu047
- Ungar, I.A. 1978. Halophyte Seed Germination. Botanical Review 44(2): 233-264

Comment: Thank you for your helpful post, it was exactly what I was looking for.